# HP 1910 Configuration Question

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve

So i have a customer who purchased 5 HP 1910 switches (4 24port and 1 8port switch). They currently have a flat network using 192.168.80.x/24 subnet. They are adding voice and wanto to segregate their network using vlans. It's been a while since i've configured HP switches (these are web based GUI's) and i wanted to confirm my config appears correct.

Managment: Vlan1 - 10.10.1.X/28
Data: Vlan10 - 192.168.80.X/24
Voice: Vlan20 - 172.16.80.X

Cisco Router (running BGP) > Core switch > 4 distribution switches > LAN

Using 1 of the 24port 1910's as a Layer 3 Core switch i've configured it the folowing way:

- IP: 10.10.1.2
- Port 28: SFP Trunk port to the 8port HP 1910 switch connected via Fiber
- Port 24: Trunk port to the Cisco Router (should this be a trunk or "Hybrid" port?)
- Port 23: Trunk port connected to the 2nd 24port HP1910 switch
- Port 22: Trunk port connected to the 3rd 24port HP1910 switch
- Port 21: Trunk port connected to the 4th 24port HP1910 switch
- Configured Vlan10 with IP 192.168.80.X with IP helper going to a remote site DHCP server
- Configured Vlan20 with IP 172.168.80.X with IP helper going to a remote site DHCP server

For the Distribution switches they configured as follows:

- 2nd: IP 10.10.1.3
- 3rd: IP 10.10.1.4
- 4th: IP 10.10.1.5
- 5th (remote): IP 10.10.1.6

Switches 2-4 are configured identically:

- Ports 1-23 are untagged in Vlan1 and 10, tagged in Vlan20 with PVID 1
- Port 24 is the uplink port to the core switch configured as a trunk
- I've configured the Vlan's on the switch as well but did not assign them IP's (i set to to "DHCP") assuming they would get their IP's from the DHCP server

Switch 5:

- Port 1-8 are untagged in Vlan1 and 10, tagged in Vlan20 with PVID 1
- Port 9 is the uplink port to the core switch configured as a trunk with a fiber SFP

My question really is will it work the way i think it should? IE if i plug a PC in any of the distribution switches it should grab a Vlan10 IP, likewise if i plug a phone into a port it should grab a Vlan20 IP?

As it stands i can ping the distribution switches from the core and vice versa. I didn't have any way of testing the Vlan's. I'm a little confused as when to use a Trunk port and when to use a Hybrid port as HP's terminology differs from Cisco's.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is invalid to configure *more than one* untagged VLAN per port. Into which VLAN does an untagged packet belong? Thus, VLAN 1 (management) should exist, and be the PVID, only on trunk ports. (PVID 10 everywhere else.)

Second, unless a switch is acting as a router (eg. the core switch), it doesn't need an ip on any non-management interfaces. Thus, the default gateway for devices in VLANs 10 and 20 (and 1) should be the relevant address of the core switch.

With this setup, the VoIP devices need to know to use VLAN 20. This can be via direct configuration, maybe DHCP(???), or CDP/LLDP<sup>[1]</sup>.

<sup>[1] Disable "Voice VLAN Security". Enable LLDP-MED.</sup>

Comment: Multiple untagged VLAN per port is perfectly valid, that's what hybrid ports are for. It only doesn't apply to inter-switch links - those should be trunks. Some older IP phones don't do dot1q so 2 untagged VLANs is necessary for daisy-chaining phones and PCs. These phones apparently do, so for edge ports unt VLAN 10 / tag VLAN 20 is the way to go. When Voice VLAN is enabled, switch will identify voice traffic by the source MAC and place it to Voice VLAN. With FW R1513 switch identifies 7 manufacturer OUIs, and others can be manually added.

Comment: When V-VLAN security is enabled, only packets whose source MAC complies to the OUI list will be passed, others dropped. However in normal mode all packets are passing, so when daisy-chaining PCs with phones V-VLAN security mode indeed shouldn't be used, but normal mode instead. The switch manual contains a detailed description when and how to use Voice VLAN.

Comment: Well, that's certainly inventive. I've never met a voip phone that didn't do 802.1q. What you've described isn't "multiple untagged vlans", but *one* untagged and *one* brain damaged vlan sequestered by some hand waving in the switch. There can't be multiple untagged vlans due to the confusion of to what vlan a packet belongs -- in this case, that's *mac vlans*

Comment: I support @Ricky comment. No more than one untagged VLAN per port (indeed, I think most of switches doesn't allow it). No need for IP in VLAN 10 and 20 for HP switches. I will add another advice, why use native vlan for management instead of another ID. I don't like to use ID 1 under any circunstances.